# C# - convert DeviceUniqueId (string) to int

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to get a unique id in windows phone 8 . 
I used DeviceUniqueId with the following code :

```
byte[] id = (byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
        iden = BitConverter.ToString(id).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

now I want to convert it to int 
how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have string iden, convert it to int like this:

int devId= Convert.ToInt32(iden);

Comment: it doesn't work and it cause a debugger Break . device id include 0-9 and a-f charecters .

Comment: You cannot. You can simply TryParse to see if it will parse
Atmost, you can calculate ASCII value from the characters

Comment: isn't it possible to change this string to another string then again turn back it to first string . for example change "hello" to "ehlol" then convert it back again into "hello" . Did you get my mind ?

Comment: It is normal string manipulation ,you should be able to do this.you can add int value to char(eg. if 1 added to 'e' it becomes h) or swap chars from string by using indexes.anyways it will be your choice.